# Have such exception using JPA java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hibernate.Test

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa

I decided to use Hibernate thru JPA, when I used purely Hibernate it worked just fine, now it shows me this exception

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -Didea.launcher.port=7537 -Didea.launcher.bin.path=/home/greg/idea-IC-141.1532.4/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/home/greg/IdeaProjects/EventsOnMap/target/test-classes:/home/greg/IdeaProjects/EventsOnMap/target/classes:/home/greg/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api/1.0.1.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar:/home/greg/.m2/repository/org/postgresql/postgresql/9.3-1102-jdbc41/postgresql-9.3-1102-jdbc41.jar:/home/greg/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/4.2.1.Final/hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.1.Final.jar:/home/greg/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.1.0.GA/jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar:/home/greg/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.2.1.Final/hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:/home/greg/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/home/greg/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:/home/greg/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/transaction/jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec/1.0.1.Final/jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar:/home/greg/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.15.0-GA/javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar:/home/greg/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/4.0.1.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar:/home/greg/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar:/home/greg/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/home/greg/idea-IC-141.1532.4/lib/idea_rt.jar com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain hibernate.Test
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hibernate.Test
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:122)
```

here is my POM file

```
<groupId>EventsOnMap</groupId>
    <artifactId>EventsOnMap</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.3-1102-jdbc41</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

here is Persistence.xml which is in resources/META-INF

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
                                 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
             version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="DB" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>


        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.cfgfile" value="recources/hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/journey"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="postgres"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="password"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and the hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">     
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>       
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/journey</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
              <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property> 
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>       
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>   
        <mapping class="home.map.events.entity.BaseEntity"/>
        <mapping class="home.map.events.entity.UserDetail"/>
        <mapping class="home.map.events.entity.Event"/>
        <mapping class="home.map.events.entity.Route"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Please post the full text of the exception, with stacktrace. I doubt that the title that I see is the fully exception text.

Comment: show us line number 120 to 130 from AppMain.java and highlight line number 122.

Comment: Well, I don`t have that class... it is not highlighting tough

Comment: It seems as if your project was not compiled correctly by your IDE, in this case IntelliJ, as we can assume, that "hibernate.Test" is the class that you are trying to launch somehow? Pls check if IntelliJ compiled your class/project and that it has a valid "main(...)" method. Though, by the information you provided, the project setup/structure is quite unclear... :/